# Distribute a binary executable of a program built with OpenCV?

Tags: c, installation, opencv, executable

I created a program in C that uses OpenCV. In addition to distributing the source and make files, I would like to distribute a Win32 binary that will run when an end-user clicks on it. Presumably I would need an easy way for the user to install the OpenCV libraries.  What is the best way to do this?

Should I be looking into installers, like NSIS? Any tutorials or starting points would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include the dll files of OpenCV along with your program. Put those files where your main .exe file is and it will run whether you have OpenCV installed or not.